# how can I add new Named Individual to XML/RDF owl file?

Tags: php, sparql, jena, fuseki

I am working with apache jena fuseki. I have to get some variables from php web page and send it to apache jena fuseki sparql form.

I want to insert new individual to my ontology ? But I haven't got any idea about this. this is the part of my file. I want to insert another individual like this with sparql query?

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#"
 xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:uni="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#"
 xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2"/>

 <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#Student1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#Student"/>
    <studies rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#CS101"/>
    <studies rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#M201"/>
    <studies rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#M204"/>
    <first_name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Josef</first_name>
    <last_name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Baker</last_name>
    <studentID rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">266814</studentID>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Comment: and why SPARQL? How did you create this file? And which SPARQL engine do you wnat to use? Please provide more infos. Currently, I'd also suggest to use a text editor and add the triples. Not that I'd ever work on RDF/XML manually, not sure why people don't use N-Triples or Turtle for simple RDF data

Comment: I am working with apache jena fuseki. I have to get some variables from php web page and send it to apache jena fuseki sparql form.

Comment: Following the guidance in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help us help you.

Comment: @JackJacky Then use SPARQL Update and do `INSERT DATA { ... }` W3C docs are online

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Turtle instead of RDF/XML…

Here's your current data, converted —

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix ns0: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2> 
   a               owl:Ontology .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#Student1>
   a               owl:NamedIndividual , 
                   <http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#Student> ;
   ns0:studies     ns0:CS101 , 
                   ns0:M201 , 
                   ns0:M204 ;
   ns0:first_name  "Josef"^^xsd:string ;
   ns0:last_name   "Baker"^^xsd:string ;
   ns0:studentID   266814 .
```

I bet you can see how easy it might be to copy the stanza for the "Josef" "Baker" individual, and edit it to be about "Josefine" "Chef" …

If you really need to use SPARQL, you're probably working with some tools, identifying which would make it significantly easier for us to help you.

Comment: thanks TallTed but i need insert sparql query for insert new Named Individual to save it apache jena fuseki with php.